# How to pass currently user ID/PK from view to form in Django?

Tags: django, forms, view, django-views, django-forms

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to create a form which passes the currently logged-in users ID by embedding it within a hidden field in a ModelForm.

Models.py

```
class UserPhotos(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #photos = models.ImageField(height_field=1350, width_field=1080)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        '''Change plural name'''
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'
```

Forms.py

```
class AddPhotos(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserPhotos
        fields = (
            'description','user',
        )
```

Views.py

```
def add_photo(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('my_app:login',)
    if request.POST:
        form = AddPhotos(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user=request.user
            form.save
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            context['photoAdd_form'] = form
    else:
        form = AddPhotos()
        context['photoAdd_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'main/photo_add.html', context)
```

I have tried something like this It's works, but I have no idea how to pass the ID to the init. It gave me a error :
KeyError at /add
'userID'

Forms.py

```
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  #It is works but how will i pass the data
             request = kwargs.pop('userId')
             print(request)
             super(AddPhotos, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
             self.fields['user'].initial = request.user
```

Views.py

```
def add_photo(request):
        context = {}
        user = request.user
        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('my_app:login',)
        if request.POST:
            form = AddPhotos(request.POST, userId = request.user.id)
    ...
```

Comment: If you can solve the question by yourself, please post your answer as an answer and not as an edit to the question. It is perfectly fine, to answer one's own question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the mistake I have made. Now everything is works properly.

```
if request.POST:
        form = AddPhotos(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            **obj = form.save(commit=False)**
            user = NewUser.objects.filter(userNick=user.userNick).first()
            obj.user = user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('/')
```